# building site with different panels using zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

My Site have three panels:

```
   1. guests who have access to view threads but can't reply or vote
   2. members who, with enough rep, can edit/vote others threads, and by default they can reply and have the same privileges as guests
   3. admins who can pretty much do anything
```

Is it better to use Zend_Acl ?

Or if i will use Zend_Acl no need to make separate controllers for admin and front panel ?

What if both of admin and front panel have different UI and info to display.

or what i have to do if i will do it without using zend_Acl ?

How i will manage session using Zend_Auth  for front and admin panel ?

please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I recommend using Zend "modules" make your admin panel a separate module (modules contain controllers, e.g. Admin_UsersController), add "admin" as a resource in your ACL, and ensure your Authentication Adapter treats that entire module as a resource.

Pretty vague suggestion, but it's exactly what I do, and it works great!

Comment: can u please explain in detail ?